# check file existence in FreeASPUpload

Tags: asp-classic

I want to check file if i uploaded it before. If file exist, i want to upload with different name. How to do this?

```
on error resume next
    Set Upload = New FreeASPUpload
  <!--  Upload.OverwriteFiles = False-->
    Upload.Save(UploadPathValue)
if err <> 0 then
    Response.Write(err.description)
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the filesystemobject to check if the file exists before saving it.
Here is an explanation of how to do this: [ASP fileexists](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_fileexists.asp)